# Syntax, contrastive analysis

Tags: syntactic-analysis, linguistics

Could anyone help me with this question? **What are the main types of contrast involved in contrastive analysis of syntax? Give examples.**

I tried to find answer, but unfortunately I find nothing.

Comment: Hi Alexia. I think this question would be better asked over at [linguistics.se].

Comment: From a straightforward google search, I think it is little more than what it says, analyzing syntax through comparison (between different languages).

Comment: @Mitch, my first hunch (as a comparative syntactician) was also that it just meant comparative syntax.  But it turns out that “contrastive analysis” was a theory in its own right (chiefly applied to second language acquisition).  As such, the field may have had areas of syntax or methods that were particularly prominent.  If so, then that’s what the question(er) is after.

Comment: This question is now asked [on Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/main-types-of-contrast-involved-in-contrastive-analysis-of-syntax)